# How do i install MongoDb on Ubuntu and set the config at install time

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu

I am creating an automated deployment for a cloud server and I need to get Mongodb installed, configured and running in one script. I won't have access to the server as the deployment server pulls my scripts from git.

My issue is I need to set the logpath and dbpath to another location. How do i do this using apt-get. What I use at the moment is below but it sets the path to the default location.

```
apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv 7F0CEB10
echo "deb http://downloads-distro.mongodb.org/repo/ubuntu-upstart dist 10gen" | tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/10gen.list
apt-get -y update
apt-get -y install mongodb-10gen
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To do this easily, write the mongodb.conf first yourself (use sudo, create it as /etc/mongodb.conf with permissions of 644 and root:root) - use an existing one as a template or grab it [from git](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/master/debian/mongodb.conf) and alter the dbpath and logpath appropriately.

Also easy - just remove those default folders and create symbolic links to point at your desired install paths - no modification to files necessary at all.

If, for some reason you don't want to do that, and you want to do it post-install, then you are going to have to stop the service from starting up with the configured file so that it doesn't start up, pre-allocate files etc.  There are a couple of options to do that, that have been covered in pretty decent detail [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=856815).

As described there, your options are to either temporarily block all new services from starting or do a download-only fetch with apt-get and manipulate the files to not start mongod automatically before you install, or alter the package to manipulate the config file before it starts.

Or, finally, you can install as normal and let it start, then stop the mongod service (`service mongod stop`), remove the files that were created in the configured paths, and then alter the mongodb.conf with your new values (or overwrite with your own), restart the service.

Comment: I tried to use an altered version of the mongodb.conf template, but it gets overwritten by the default one when the package installs

Comment: that is not what happened to my pre-existing file when I tested it, on  Ubuntu and with a file in place - it remained intact.  This was afer a remove/reinstall because I had already installed it previously, I will try fresh.

Comment: Doh - that was my fault bad path for copy. the config copies fine. My issue now is the journal doesn't move and i can't seem to set its location or disable it -  Please make at least 3379MB available in /data/db/journal or use --smallfiles

Comment: The smallfiles option can be problematic if you grow your data set significantly, but would be OK for testing or a small database.  If you want to move the journal elsewhere (it will follow --dbpath) besides your data folder, then I would recommend the symlink option I mentioned - just remove the current one (if not a fresh install) and then symlink the journal folder to your desired location.  You can also run without the journal (--nojournal) but that is not generally recommended if you want to keep your data consistent

Comment: I set nojournal to true with no effect and the dbpath is not /data/db. I dont think the mongodb.config is getting picked up.

Comment: double check the permissions of the config file (has to be readable `o+r` for the mongodb user to pick it up - it does not run as root) and where the upstart script is pointing to with -f when it is starting the mongod

Comment: This worked eventually with one addition. I had to add a "nohup" command when i started the service as mongodb aparantly leaves a filedescriptor open that caused everything to shutdown when the session exited.